# Finding the positive \ negative domain of a simple expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the right domain of a simple expression,

I tried to check the positive domain of this function:

$$ \frac{{900-6X} }{X+50} > 0$$

$$900-6X > 0 $$

$$900 > 6X$$

$$ 150 > X$$

but intuitively, I see it is not right, because when $X$ will be smaller than $-49$ the expression will be negative)

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The "split point method" works well here.  Find all the points where the left side is equal to zero or discontinuous.

The left side is $0$ when $x=150$ and it has a discontinuity at $x=-50.$

Plot these points on a number line and they divide the number line into 3 regions.  Pick a point from each region and see if it makes the inequality true.  If one point from a region is true, then the whole region is true.

So try $x=-100$.  It makes the inequality false.  So the whole region less than $x=-50$ is NOT part of the solution.

Now try $x=0$.  It makes the inequality true.  So the whole region from $x=-50$ to $x=150$ is part of the solution set.

Finally try $x=200.$  It makes the inequality false, so the whole region is NOT part of the solution.

Now gather up all the true regions:  There is only one:  $-50 < x <150.$

Answer (score 0):

You can go from $\frac{900-6X}{X+50}>0$ to $900-6X>0$ only if $X+50$ is positive. If it is negative, you must flip the inequality sign.

Answer (score 0):

For a quotient to be positive, you need either both the numerator and denominator to be positive or both to be negative.

So $\frac{900-6X}{X+50}>0$ is not equivalent to $900-6X>0$. The right equivalence is

$$\frac{900-6X}{X+50}>0\iff \left(900-6X>0\land X+50>0\right)\lor\left(900-6X<0\land X+50<0\right)$$